# Running custom alias command in terminal results in "command not found"

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, command-line-interface, alias

On my macbook pro, I'm trying to create a quick command to check my home internet speed.

This [website](http://best-mac-tips.com/2013/09/23/test-internet-speed-command-line-terminal/) provided the command I use :

```
curl -O http://speedtest.wdc01.softlayer.com/downloads/test10.zip > /dev/null
```

I'd really not like to type this command every time so I created an alias called "ispeed" by running

```
Users-MacBook-Pro:~ user$ sudo nano /.bash_profile
```

[image]

**However**, when closing terminal and opening a fresh one, I try the new command:

```
Users-MacBook-Pro:~ user$ ispeed
```

and get the following:

```
-bash: ispeed: command not found
```

How to fix?

Comment: `/.bash_profile` is not the same as `~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: @Benjamin W  But I was in my home folder?  What changes when I put a "~" in front?

Comment: `/.bash_profile` is an absolute path to the file `.bash_profile` in the root folder, `/` (and that file doesn't exist), so no matter where you are, it'll will try to find it in the root folder. `~/.bash_profile` is also an absolute path, but to your home folder, where the file actually is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the alias command in `~/.bash_profile`:

```
alias ispeed='curl -O http://speedtest.wdc01.softlayer.com/downloads/test10.zip > /dev/null'
```

And then, make sure to write it out correctly (Save the file).  After you properly save the alias and `nano` or whatever text editor you're using is exited, you should get your command prompt line back.  **It won't work in that shell though, you need to open a new one**.  Press `cmd + t` to open a new tab and then try the command `ispeed` and it should work.

Comment: this did it, thanks!